# onclick toggle of an object NOT button

Tags: javascript, onclick

So I wrote this code and I'm trying to not have a button or link that toggles the visibility of an object. I want to reference an object that I created earlier. How do you reference an object?

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">map layer visibility</a>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

I believe it is because I am saying an a href so that is why I can only currently do a link.

Comment: Sorry so do you want a button or not? Im confused?

Comment: I'm also a little confused. Can you please also show the `toggle_visibility()` code and try to explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Your `toggle_visibility` function should call `document.getElementById` to get the foo element. The `onclick` should also return false if you don't want it to do more than toggling the visibility. Not sure that this answers your question...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm trying to toggle visibility with an onclick. However I do not want to create a button that does this. I created a var in my code and I want that var to toggle visibility. I am not sure of the syntax since all I could find was either making a button, link, or image.